# How to match--but not capture--in Python regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I've got a function spitting out "Washington D.C., DC, USA" as output. I need to capture "Washington, DC" for reasons that have to do with how I handle every single other city in the country. (Note: this is **not** the same as "D.C.", I need the comma to be between "Washington" and "DC", whitespace is fine)

I can't for the life of me figure out how to capture this.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    >>>location = "Washington D.C., DC, USA"

    >>>match = re.search(r'\w+\s(?:D\.C\.), \w\w(?=\W)', location).group()
    >>>match
    u'Washington D.C., DC'
```

Is not (?: ...) supposed to just match (and not capture) "D.C."?

Here are the 2.7.2 Docs:

> (?:...)
>   A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

What gives??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's a clever way indeed, but not-capturing doesn't mean removing it from match. It just mean, that it's not considered as an output group.

You should try to do something similar to the following:

```
match = re.search(r'(\w+)\s(?:D\.C\.), (\w\w)\W', location).groups()
```

This prints `('Washington', 'DC')`.

Note the difference between `.group()` and `.groups()`. The former gives you the whole string that was matched, the latter only the captured groups. Remember, you need to specify what you want to *include* in the output, not what you want to exclude.

Answer (score 6):

```
matches = re.search(r'(\w+\s)(?:D\.C\.)(, \w\w)(?=\W)', location).group(1,2)
match = ''.join(matches)
```

When it says it is "non-capturing", that means it won't make a separate captured group for it.  The text "D.C." is still in the match.  See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects

Comment: Right, I think the OP's real issue is that `group()` with no arguments returns the whole string that was matched. Aside from calling `group()` with args, the other way to work with python on this is to call `groups()` and capture the sub-matches (which would correctly exclude the "D.C."

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this and the first two answers were great, but if by any chance you need a general regex for pulling cities out of a combination of cities, suffixes, states/provinces, and countries, but you know D.C. is an annoying special case, you might be able to use the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> city = re.compile(r'(\w+(?:\sD\.C\.)?), \w\w(?=\W)')
>>> location = "Washington D.C., DC, USA"
>>> re.search(city, location).group(1)
'Washington D.C.'
>>> location = "Vancouver, BC, Canada"
>>> re.search(city, location).group(1)
'Vancouver'
```

The D.C. part is made optional (as you don't always need it) in addition to being non-capturing (to save memory).